# Linked List Crashes after all nodes are deleted

Tags: c++, linked-list

Our homework assignment wanted us to create a "Staque" (implements features of a stack and a queue) using a linked list. When entering even numbers in the list, they should go to the top of the list and odd numbers at the bottom. So if the values inserted are 8 1 4 6 7 9 it should output 6 4 8 1 7 9. Then you delete the top two even numbers and the bottom odd number which would give 8 1 7. Everything seems to work fine except when all the nodes are deleted so when you enter 3 or less values, the program crashes. At this time I have to turn in my assignment since it's due tonight but am just wondering how this can be resolved. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

Driver:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Staq.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Staq *std = new Staq();

    int numofvals;
    int i;
    int x;
    cout << "How many values in the staque?" << endl;
    cin >> numofvals;
    cout << numofvals << " values will be entered in the staque." << endl << endl;;

    for(i=1; i<=numofvals; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value " << i << ":" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        std->AddNode(x);
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Staque:" << endl;
    std->PrintList();

    std->DeleteNode();

    cout << "\nStaque after deletions:" << endl;

    std->PrintList();

    return 0;
}
```

.CPP:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Staq.h"

Staq::Staq()
{
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void Staq::AddNode(int addData)
{
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if(addData % 2 == 0)
    {
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            curr = n;
        }
        else
        {
            n->next = head;
            head = n;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            curr = n;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = head;
            while(temp->next != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = n;
        }
    }
}

void Staq::DeleteNode()
{
    nodePtr temp2 = new node;

    if(head->data %2 == 0)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;

        if(head->data %2 == 0)
        {
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    temp = head;

    while(temp->next->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if(temp->data %2 != 0)
    {
        temp2 = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
        delete temp2;
    }

}

void Staq::PrintList()
{
    curr = head;

    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Header:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef STAQ_H
#define STAQ_H

class Staq
{
public:
    Staq();
    ~Staq();

    void AddNode(int addData);
    void DeleteNode();
    void PrintList();

private:
    class node
    {
    public:
        int data;
        node* next;
    };

    typedef class node* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DeleteNode`, you attempt to access the first node's data, even if there isn't a node. Same goes for the second node.

`while(temp->next->next)` is dangerous because `temp->next` could be `NULL` therefore making `temp->next->next` an access to null pointer. I assume you meant `temp->next`. You might want to validate `temp` too.

Finally, although unrelated, `temp2 = temp->next` causes a memory leak because now no one points to the new node created at the beginning of `DeleteNode`.